# Affine invariant representation of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, affine-geometry

I figure there is probably an answer to this, but I'm not sure I'm using the appropriate search terms online. I'm interested in whether or not there exist affine invariant representations of arbitrary real vectors. Specifically, if you have a vector $v_i$ and a transformed vector $Av_i + b$ (**where we assume that $A$ is diagonal with the same element in each position, i.e. $A=\alpha I$, and $b$ is a constant vector**), can we construct some function $\tau$ (the image of which is a vector) so that $\tau (v_i) = \tau (Av_i + b)$?

---

If we consider only one operation (either scalar multiplication or addition by constant vector), than we can easily find such a construction. Denote by $\alpha v_i$ scalar multiplication where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. By taking contiguous ratios of the $k$-th and $(k+1)$th components, we have a function the image of which is equal for both vectors. For instance, let $v_i = (0.5, 1.0, 2.0)$ and $4v_i = (2.0, 4.0, 8.0)$. If we set the first value to $1.0$ by convention, then we have a $\tau (v_i) = (1.0, 2.0, 2.0) = \tau (4v_i)$.

We can do something very similar for addition of a constant vector $K \in \mathbb{R}$: instead of taking contiguous ratios, we take contiguous differences. If $v_j = (0.5, 1.0, 1.25)$ and $K=$**3**$= (3.0, 3.0, 3.0)$, then we have that $v_j + K = (3.5, 4.0, 4.25)$. By setting a first value to $0.0$ (also convention) and taking differences of contiguous elements for each vector, we get that $\omega (v_j) = (0.0, 0.5, 0.25) = \omega (v_j + K)$.

---

But can we find such a function if we're doing both operations simultaneously (scalar multiplication=multiplication by diagonal matrix **and** addition by a constant vector), i.e. if we apply an affine transformation to the vector? Apologies if this isn't totally clear –– I'm happy to clarify any points in the comments.

Comment: It's not really clear what you call a 'representation' of a vector. It seems that they are kind of arbitrary functions $\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$ (your two examples doesn't really seem to have more in common, e.g. none of them are linear).

Comment: Apologies –– I know that "representation" has a very specific algebraic meaning, so it's probably not the best use of the word. In your words: I wonder whether there exists a function the image of which is equivalent for two vectors, one of which is an affine transformation of the other. One way seems to be taking ratios *of* the contiguous differences, but this reduces dimensionality and also creates problems with division by zero.